# Understanding test driven approach for MVP pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, mvp

I am learning about MVP, test driven approach and factory pattern. I want to write few simple classes for maintaining a person's data and repository. The person's data will be stored in sql and for testing in an xml. I read about StructureMap but do not want to use it instead want to use a simple factory implementation that can eventually also help me hooking in unit test cases. Here are my classes:

```
class Person
{
    int id;
    string name;
}

interface IPersonRepository
{
    Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
    }
}

class PersonRepositorySql : IPersonRepository
{
    Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        //Fetch from sql
    }
}

class PersonRepositoryXML : IPersonRepository
{
    Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        //Fetch from XML
    }
}

static class PersonRepositoryFactory
{
    static PersonRepositorySql Create()
    {
        return new PersonRepositorySql();
    }

    static PersonRepositoryXML CreateTest()
    {
        return new PersonRepositoryXML();
    }
}

class Presenter
{
    Presenter(View _view)
    {
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        IPersonRepository fact = PersonRepositoryFactory.Create();
        //fact.GetPerson(2);
    }

}

class PresenterTest
{
    void Test1()
    {
        IPersonRepository fact1 = PersonRepositoryFactory.CreateTest();
        //fact1.GetPerson(2);
    }
}
```

Please tell me if the approach I have taken is the right one and any other recommendations. Also since I have not passed objects in constructor does this no stand as an example of dependency injection?

Comment: Nothing is based on abstractions that are injected.. which is a core component of testing and TDD. I think you should re-read your reference material, specifically the parts about tight coupling and concrete implementations.. and dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

First of all **don't** depend on classes if you want to have your code testable, depend on **interface** that is implemented by a class.

Classes that depend on your factories should expect it *injected* by their users. Thanks to this you can swap your repository in test project easily and without changes to tested code.

Therefore any factory you have should be changed to something like this:

```
class PersonRepositoryXML: IPersonRepository
{
    public IPerson GetPerson(int id)
    {
        //Fetch from XML
    }
}

public interface IPersonRepository
{
    IPerson GetPerson(int id);
}

// a dependent class
class SomeDependentClass {
    public SomeDependentClass(IPersonRepository repository) {
         this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void Foo() {
         var person = repository.GetPerson(10);
         // do smth to the person :)
    }
}
```

I would recommend reading [this](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) book for further details about Dependency Injection design pattern.

Comment: Thanks. Just edited my answer according to your recommendations. I added an interface for PersonRepository but should I add an interface also for PersonRepositoryFactory? What benefit will it provide when I can already switch to XML or SQl repository...

Comment: I wouldn't personally use factory. I would use dependency container to bind things together. If you don't want to use DI libraries I still would wrap repository into interface so it is easier to test things related to that factory.